# How to set default text editor in ranger? My shell is fish

Tags: linux, shell, fish

When I'm trying open some text document using ranger and having this error:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: vim: command not found
```

I have this strokes in config.fish:

```
set EDITOR "nvim"
set VISUAL "nvim"
```

I'm using fish as my shell.
How can I set up default editor in ranger without changing rifle.conf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any options the [`set`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html) command only sets variable locally and doesn't export it.

For global variables that should be exported (like the `EDITOR` variable should be) then use the `-g` and `-x` options:

```
set -gx EDITOR "nvim"
set -gx VISUAL "nvim"
```

The most important option is the `-x` option. From the previously linked reference:

> Causes the specified shell variable to be exported to child processes (**making it an “environment variable”**)

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>